# '='を含むターゲットのMake

Tags: makefile

通常、ターゲット`hello_world`をmakeするときには、

```
make hello_world
```

とします。
同じ要領で、ターゲット`hello=world`をmakeしようとして、

```
make hello=world
```

とすると、意図した結果にはなりません（変数`hello`の値を`world`に設定して、デフォルトターゲットがmakeされます）。

これを`hello=world`のmakeであると認識させるにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

一般論としてmakeのターゲット名に'='を使うべきでないことは理解していますが、やむをえない事情によりwork-aroundを探しています。

---

状況を再現する最小構成
GNU Make 4.2.1 on cygwin x86_64

`Makefile`の内容(スペースはタブに変更してください)

```
HELLO:=hello=world
all:       # "all world"
    @echo all $(hello)
$(HELLO):  # "hello=world"
    @echo hello=world $(hello)
```

普通に実行

```
$ make hello=world
all world
```

シングルクォートして実行

```
$ make 'hello=world'
all world
```

ダブルクォートして実行

```
$ make "hello=world"
all world
```

エスケープして実行

```
$ make hello\=world
all world
```

シングルクォート＋エスケープして実行

```
$ make 'hello\=world'
all
```

ダブルクォート＋エスケープして実行

```
$ make "hello\=world"
all
```

Comment: GNU make のドキュメントには "Any target in the makefile may be specified as a goal (**unless it starts with ‘-’ or contains an ‘=’, in which case it will be parsed as a switch or variable definition, respectively**)" という記述があります。

Comment: ご紹介ありがとうございます。そのドキュメントは読んだうえで、あえて迂回策を探していましたが、やはり無理筋かもしれませんね。

Comment: まぁ、ターゲット `$(HELLO):` を `$(subst =,-,$(HELLO)):` などに書き換えれば `make hello-world` とできますが、本末転倒ですね…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

これでいかがでしょうか。

```
luna:~ % make --version | head -1
GNU Make 4.2.1
luna:~ % make .DEFAULT_GOAL=hello=world
hello=world
luna:~ %
```

Answer (score 1):

Makefile 中の変数 `HELLO` を上書きしてしまってよいなら、

```sh
make HELLO=hello_world hello_world
```

でいいですね。
ただ、実際に問題になっている Makefile では `HELLO` はもっと複雑な使われ方をしていて、簡単に触れないのでしょうね。

Makefile の冒頭に記述を足してしまっては駄目でしょうか。
一時ファイルを作らないとすると、例えば以下のような方法が考えられます。

```sh
printf 'MY_TARGET=hello=world\nmy_target: $(MY_TARGET)\n' |cat - Makefile |make -f -
```

Comment: @masm さんの回答のほうがシンプルですが、 `.DEFAULT_GOAL` の上書きが問題を起こすケースでは、この方法が役立ちますね。+1